# Extract middle name from web page using R

Tags: r, rvest

I have this [book's Google webpage](https://books.google.com/books?id=qEELS7T_Tm0C&dq=NHL%20teams&source=gbs_navlinks_s) - and the author is `Glenn M. Wong`, right under the main title.

I want to extract the middle name using the typical `rvest` method. Eg, to get the last name only:

```
last_name <- url %>% 
  html_nodes('#bookinfo div:nth-child(1) span') %>% 
  html_text %>% 
  sub(".* ", "", .)
```

And then the first name:

```
first_name <- url %>% 
  html_nodes('#bookinfo div:nth-child(1) span') %>% 
  html_text %>% 
  sub(" .*", "", .)
```

How do I just get the middle name? In this case it's just the initial, but in case of full name, I'd want the whole thing. This does not work:

```
sub(" .* ", "", .)
```

If only first/last names are there, code works great. But if middle name is present, everything goes to hell. What's the best way to extract the middle name, if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
sub("^[^\\s]+\\s(.*)\\s.*$", "\\1", .)
```

Full code

```
url <- "https://books.google.de/books?id=qEELS7T_Tm0C&dq=NHL+teams&source=gbs_navlinks_s&redir_esc=y"

library(rvest)
url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('#bookinfo div:nth-child(1) span') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  sub("^[^\\s]+\\s(.*)\\s.*", "\\1", .)
# [1] "M."
```